# Webpy doesn't validates form

Tags: python, forms, web.py

Webpy validates form from /search page only if I do my request for the first time.

So, I start at index page and put data in textbox then I see that form validated correctly and /search shows exactly what i want. After that, I'm trying to use form from /search page but it doest work.

I use Ubuntu, Python 2.7.3 and webpy 0.37

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/search/', 'Search',
)

render = web.template.render('templates/')
search_form = web.form.Form(
        web.form.Textbox('text',
            size=30,
            description='Text'),
        web.form.Button('Apply'),
        validators = [web.form.Validator("This field should be filled",
                                        lambda i: i.text != '')]
    )


class Index:

    def GET(self):
        form = search_form()
        text = 'Hello'
        return render.index(form, text)

    def POST(self):
        form = search_form()
        if not form.validates():
           text = 'Bad Text'
           return render.index(form, text)
        else:
           url = '?text=%s' % form.d.text
           web.seeother('/search/' + url)
class Search:

    def GET(self):
        form = search_form()
        input = web.input(text="None")
        text = input.text
        return render.search(form, text)

    def POST(self):
        form = search_form()
        if not form.validates():
           text = 'Bad Text'
           return render.index(form, text)
        else:
           url = '?text=%s' % form.d.text
           web.seeother('/search/' + url)

class MyApplication(web.application):
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('127.0.0.1', port))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication(urls, globals())
    app.run(port=8081)
```

templates index.html and search.html

```
$def with (form, text)
<form action="" method="POST">
$:form.render()
</form>

<h1>$text</h>
```

I tried to solve this problem many times and googled all about form processing in webpy.
According to [documentation and examples](http://webpy.org/), I think my code shuld works fine. Maybe something wrong with see other

Comment: What's the specific problem? Form validation works on `/` but not on `/search`? Does the form submission as a whole work (e.g. the bad data is passed through to the app without validation?

Comment: It works on both / and /search (it shows message when you give bad data and redirect to another page) but it works just for the first click.Example: 1. I open / page 2. I pass data to form and click "Apply" 2. I see that i've been redirected to /search and see my data. 3. I pass new data to form at page /search and click "Apply" 4.Nothing happened. I see the same page as at step 2. Moreover. Server log showed that i've been redirected. 5. I pass bad data to form but i see result as at step 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [example](http://webpy.org/src/blog/0.3), I tried to change my approch to processing input from url.
So, Instead of using standart web.input() method, I added regular expresion to urls

```
urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/search/text=(.*)', 'Search',
)
```

and got access to variable directly in body of the class Search.

```
#variable text contains the regexp from url
class Search
    def GET(self, text):
        form = search_form()
        return render.search(form, str(text))
```

Finally, form on /search page begun to work fine. Now it validates a user input and the page /search print right output, no matter how many times user used this form.

Working code:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/search/text=(.*)', 'Search',
)

render = web.template.render('templates/')

search_form = web.form.Form(
        web.form.Textbox(
            'text',
            web.form.regexp(r"\S+", "It mustn't be empty"),
            size=30,
            description='Text'),
        web.form.Button('Apply'),
    )

class Index:

    def GET(self):
        form = search_form()
        text = 'Hello'
        return render.index(form, text)

    def POST(self):
        form = search_form()
        if not form.validates():
           text = 'Bad Text'
           return render.index(form, text)
        else:
           url = '/search/text=%s' % form.d.text
           web.seeother(url)

class Search:

    def GET(self, text):
        form = search_form()
        return render.search(form, str(text))

    def POST(self, text):
        form = search_form()
        if not form.validates():
           text = 'Bad Text'
           return render.index(form, str(text))
        else:            
           url = '/search/text=%s' % form.d.text
           web.seeother(url)

class MyApplication(web.application):          
    def run(self, port=8080, *middleware):
        func = self.wsgifunc(*middleware)
        return web.httpserver.runsimple(func, ('127.0.0.1', port))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApplication(urls, globals())
    app.run(port=8102)
```